# Could someone help on this Markov Chain Question？

Tags: linear-algebra

Well, I've been reading over the internet but I've been unable to find a straight answer.  Can someone help me?

Let
$$P= \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    P^1 \\
    P^2 \\
    P^3 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]$$be a vector of sunny, cloudy, and rainy, respectively.  Suppose that the probability on day $n$ satisfies
$P_{n+1}=AP_n$, with $$A= \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    0.8&0.2&0.2 \\
    0.1&0.7&0.2 \\
    0.1&0.1&0.6 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right].$$
When today’s weather is sunny, i.e.,
$$P_0= \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right],$$
find the value of $P_\infty$.

I have done this step, do not know what to do next
$$P_n=A^nP_0=Q\Lambda^nQ^{-1}P_0=\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    2.5&0&-1 \\
    1.5&-1&1 \\
    1&1&0 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right] \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    1&0&0 \\
    0&0.5&0 \\
    0&0&0.6^n \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]^n\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    0.2&0.2&0.2\\
    -0.2&-0.2&0.8 \\
   -0.5&0.5&0.5 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    1\\
    0\\
    0\\
    \end{matrix}
\right].$$

Comment: The only thing remaining after diagonalization is matrix multiplication. It should be the very first thing you learn.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to find the eigenspace with eigenvalue $1$, since that is the steady state for this Markov chain.

In other words to solve the equation $$Mv = v \Leftrightarrow (M-I)v = 0$$

For stochastic matrices we can prove we will have one unique eigenvalue 1 and the rest of them will be $\in [0,1[$, so they will be 0 when raised to $\infty$

Numerically we can find the eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ : $$[0.81\cdots, 0.4822\cdots, 0.3244\cdots]^T$$

But we can clearly see that this vector is not normalized to sum to $1$ which is a prerequisite for a probability measure, so we need to do renormalization also by dividing by sum of elements, and then we get:

$$[0.5,0.3,0.2]^T$$

So 50% chance sunny, 30% cloudy and 20% rainy.

Now you can check the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As a beginner, I can't understand your answer. If possible，could you please take a look at the steps I did？ I just edited the question. Thanks again.@mathreadler